# Counting function calls in the Towers of Hanoi?

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

So I want to count how many time the function moveSingleDisk() is called, but I can't seem to figure it out... Using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void moveTower(int n, char start, char finish, char temp, int count);
void moveSingleDisk(char moveFrom, char moveTo, int count);
void calcHanoi(int n);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    calcHanoi(5);
    return 0;
}

void calcHanoi(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    moveTower(n, 'A', 'B', 'C', count);
}

void moveTower(int n, char start, char finish, char temp, int count)
{
    if (n == 1) 
    {
        count++;
        moveSingleDisk(start, finish, count);
        return;
    }
    moveTower(n-1, start, temp, finish, count);
    count++;
    moveSingleDisk(start, finish, count);
    moveTower(n-1, temp, finish, start, count);
}

void moveSingleDisk(char moveFrom, char moveTo, int count)
{
    cout << count << ": " << moveFrom << " -> " << moveTo << endl;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
1: A -> B
1: A -> C
2: B -> C
1: A -> B
2: C -> A
2: C -> B
3: A -> B
1: A -> C
2: B -> C
2: B -> A
3: C -> A
2: B -> C
3: A -> B
3: A -> C
4: B -> C
1: A -> B
2: C -> A
2: C -> B
3: A -> B
2: C -> A
3: B -> C
3: B -> A
4: C -> A
2: C -> B
3: A -> B
3: A -> C
4: B -> C
3: A -> B
4: C -> A
4: C -> B
5: A -> B
```

I've tried to trace the problem, but recursion makes tracing this type of thing quite difficult (at least for me).

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you just use a static variable? Or if you want to keep the basics of your code then don't pass count by value but by reference or as a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `count` by value, so the recursive calls to `moveTower` don't modify the local copy of it. Pass by reference instead:

```
void moveTower(int n, char start, char finish, char temp, int & count)
                                                              ^
```

It might be slightly neater to increment the counter inside `moveSingleDisk`, rather than before each call to it, so you can be sure that you don't miss any calls. In that case, you'll need to pass by reference there too.

Comment: Eh, such a beginner mistake :P Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 3):

if you simply need count calls of `moveSingleDisk`, just make in the `moveSingleDisk`

```
static int count = 0;
count++;
```

look at this example, you don't need to pass counter parameter

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(){
  static int i = 0;
  cout << i++;
  return i < 5 ? f() : 5;
}

int main(){
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner, tbh, as it emphasizes the idea that the counter pertains specifically to the `moveSingleDisk` function and is state for that function.

Answer (score 1):

Working with recursive data/algorithms, a functional approach can simplify the code: return the count from your recursive functions, 'aggregating' the nested levels. But this way you will lose the display of the 'step' count.

```
int moveTower(int n, char start, char finish, char temp);
int moveSingleDisk(char moveFrom, char moveTo);
void calcHanoi(int n);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    calcHanoi(5);
    return 0;
}

void calcHanoi(int n)
{
    int count = moveTower(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}

int moveTower(int n, char start, char finish, char temp)
{
    if (n == 1) 
        return moveSingleDisk(start, finish);
    return
        moveTower(n-1, start, temp, finish) +
        moveSingleDisk(start, finish) +
        moveTower(n-1, temp, finish, start);
}

int moveSingleDisk(char moveFrom, char moveTo)
{
    cout << moveFrom << " -> " << moveTo << endl;
    return 1;
}
```